# Hot to fix: Injecting a Fragment Array works with Java but not Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

I am gradually converting an app to Kotlin, however, there is one instance where I have an error that I can't comprehend.

My `Dagger` module contains the following:

```
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @Named("LOADING_FRAGMENTS")
        fun providesLoadingFragments(): Array<Fragment> = arrayOf(IntroFragment(), DetailsFragment(), ExitFragment())
```

The class in Java that works:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Inject
    @Named("LOADING_FRAGMENTS")
    Fragment[] fragments;

...
```

The converted class to Kotlin:

```
class LoadingActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    @Named("LOADING_FRAGMENTS")
    lateinit var fragments: Array<Fragment>
```

Only when I convert the `LoadingActivity` to Kotlin, I'm receiving the following error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] androidx.fragment.app.Fragment[] cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<packagepath.Application> {
                ^
      androidx.fragment.app.Fragment[] is injected at
          path.LoadingActivity.fragments
      path.LoadingActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [path.AppComponent ? path.contribute.ActivityContributeModule_ContributeLoadingActivity.LoadingActivitySubcomponent]
```

Can anyone help me understand why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: add `@Provides` to `fun providesLoadingFragments()`

Comment: ALso, what fragments go inside loadingactivitiy is its implementation detail. Injecting fragments like that will hinder you in future when you want to pass arguments into the fragments, etc

Comment: @Provides is there. I updated the question.

Comment: Those Fragments have another purpose, but I changed a bit the code to explain the question more clearly. My main issue is why is it not working?

Comment: There could be a number of things. I'd need to see the relevant dagger graph, meaning AppComponent, BaseActivity, BaseFragment, LoadingActivitySubcomponent, etc. In the "Build" tab, click on "Toggle view" below the hammer icon. That will show detailed errors